# TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not NoneType

Tags: python, inheritance, exception, ipython

So this has confused me for too long today.  I am tossing it up to you guys.

I am getting

```
TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not NoneType
```

even when I simply use `raise` alone or with `Exception()`

Here is the whole traceback incase it helps.  I am flummoxed...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/gus/py274/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    176             else:
    177                 filename = fname
--> 178             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/home/gus/Dropbox/repos/git/blacktie/src/blacktie/scripts/blacktie_pipeline.py in <module>()
    233 
    234 if __name__ == "__main__":
--> 235     main()

/home/gus/Dropbox/repos/git/blacktie/src/blacktie/scripts/blacktie_pipeline.py in main()
    203             # Prep cuffmerge call
    204             ##ipdb.set_trace()
--> 205             cuffmerge_call = CuffmergeCall(yargs,email_info,run_id,run_logs,conditions=experiment,mode=args.mode)
    206             cuffmerge_call.execute()
    207 

/home/gus/Dropbox/repos/git/blacktie/src/blacktie/utils/calls.pyc in __init__(self, yargs, email_info, run_id, run_logs, conditions, mode)
    627 
    628         self.prog_yargs = self.yargs.cuffmerge_options
--> 629         self.set_call_id()
    630         self.init_log_file()
    631         self.out_dir = self.get_out_dir()

/home/gus/Dropbox/repos/git/blacktie/src/blacktie/utils/calls.pyc in set_call_id(self)
    116             self.call_id = call_id
    117         else:
--> 118             raise Exception()
    119 
    120     def notify_start_of_call(self):

TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not NoneType
```

Comment: It would help to post your code. Any chance you re-define the name `Exception` in that scope to be some callable returning None?  You can turn on pdb in ipython (`%pdb`) and see what `Exception` is when it breaks.

Comment: No I have not redefined anything, and I changed `Exception` to many other derived "raisables".  Doesn't matter the specific class.  The problem was not with my code it seems.  It was coming from running the script inside of ipython. (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I seem to have found that the problem is not in my own code per se.  I had been running the script inside Ipython: hence the toplevel trace address.

I decided to run it from the terminal and the exception is raised as expected.

I answered this myself even though I still don't know why Ipython is causing this to happen because that seems like a separate question I should ask.

Hope this helps someone seeing this weird behavior though.

Comment: Thanks. I had this same problem with Ipython. It would have taken me too long to figure out it was ipython but for your answer. Thanks!